# Mongoose how to replace a Model's save() function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

I have set up a KeystoneJS project which allows you to get an out-of the box Admin UI for your models.

KeystoneJS works with only one master database, where you define models, and then each Model get its own collection in that master database.

The thing is, I have a separate user database and a separate content database. I am looking to "hijack" the Keystone Models, so that I can plug in the models from my other databases (currently using the [mongoose-glue](https://github.com/xpepermint/mongoose-glue) project).

I am 50% there. I got it to read data by replacing the Keystone model's `.find()` and `.findOne()` functions like this

```
var KeystoneUser = new keystone.List('User');
KeystoneUser.add({ /* clone all fields in external model */ });
KeystoneUser.register();

var external = require("mongoose-glue");
var ExternalUser = external.model("ExternalUser")

KeystoneUser.model.find = ExternalUser.find.bind(ExternalUser)
KeystoneUser.model.findOne = ExternalUser.findOne.bind(ExternalUser)
```

Using the above the Keystone Admin UI works super good for listing and browsing the data in the external database.

**But the problem is when it comes to saving.**

How can I replace the save function in a similar manner? Also, for some reason when doing the above, all pre/post hooks stop working on both the keystone and the external model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
KeystoneUser.model.collection = ExternalUser.collection;
```

That got the hooks to work, so then I just wrote my own save/update hook

```
KeystoneUser.schema.pre("save", function(next) {
    // Trick to remove everything we don't need
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    if (typeof this.__v === "undefined") {
        new ExternalUser(data).save();
    } else {
        delete data._id;
        ExternalUser.findByIdAndUpdate(this._id, data).exec();
    }
    next();
});
```